# ExtJS 4 - Can't get a reference to my stores in the controller

Tags: extjs, controller, store

I'm not beeing able to use the getter for my store inside my controler. I have to use the full name ('ExtMVC.store.Contatos' instead of just 'Contatos') otherwise the application just crashes... but using the full name I can't use the getter that is generated by the framework (getContatosStore). Here is my controller:

controller/Contacts.js

```
Ext.define('ExtMVC.controller.Contacts', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

models: ['Contatos'],
stores: ['ExtMVC.store.Contatos'],
views: ['ContatosGrid'],
refs: [
    {
        ref: 'contatosgrid',
        selector: 'grid',
        xtype: 'gridpanel'
    }
],
init: function() {
    this.control({
        'contatosgrid dataview': {
            itemdblclick: this.editarContato
        },
        'contatosgrid button[action=add]': {
            click: this.editarContato
        },
        'contatosgrid button[action=delete]': {
            click: this.deleteContato
        },
        'contatoform button[action=save]': {
            click: this.updateContato
        }
    });
},
editarContato: function(grid, record) {
    var edit = Ext.create('ExtMVC.view.contato.Formulario').show();

    if (record) {
       edit.down('form').loadRecord(record);
    }
},
updateContato: function(button) {
    var win = button.up('window'),
        form = win.down('form'),
        record = form.getRecord(),
        values = form.getValues();

    var novo = false;

    if (values.id > 0) {
        record.set(values);
    } else {
        record = Ext.create('ExtMVC.model.Contato');
        record.set(values);
        this.getContatosStore().add(record);
        novo = true;
    }

    win.close();
    this.getContatosStore().sync();

    if (novo) { //faz reload para atualziar
        this.getContatosStore().load();
    }
},
deleteContato: function(button) {

    var grid = this.getContatosGrid(),
        record = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection(),
        store = this.getContatosStore();

    store.remove(record);
    this.getContatosStore().sync();

    //faz reload para atualziar
    this.getContatosStore().load();
}
```

});

The views and models I can declare just using their names and everything is ok. I also tried declaring my store inside Application.js but to no avail. Any sugestions? Tnx.

Answer (score 0):

First, use short store name, not the full class name. Then check console output if there are any errors and fix them, if yes.